# P tags overriding attributes from css classes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put `<p>` tags inside a css class with `<div>`, but am getting an issue.
When I add the `<p>` tags, the background color from the class "background" disappears. The margin remains, however.
Is the `<p>` tag overriding the `<div>` tag somehow? Nothing in the css file for `<p>` affects background color so I don't know why it is being affected.

**Code**

```
<div class="background">
    <p>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
    </p>
</div>
```

And this in the css file:

```
.background {
    background-color: #303030;
    margin: 0px 250px;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: georgia;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tmfu7j32/

Comment: The markup you've posted works: http://jsfiddle.net/h6znp4h1/ – looks like something else is breaking this (unless that JSFiddle also doesn't work in your browser??)

Comment: Please try to change margin with padding: http://jsfiddle.net/mzo0egop/

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 35 on Windows 7

Comment: Yup, I'm on chrome and windows 7, and I can see the jsfiddle version in my browser fine. I can't use padding as I have background color around that which is a lighter color, I don't want the entire thing to be that color.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you want to achieve..

Comment: @wavemaster I am trying to make the background color for the class "background" (#303030) work. Currently, it is not doing anything as long as there are <p> tags nested insides the <div>.

Answer (score 0):

replace the margin with padding: http://jsfiddle.net/tmfu7j32/1/

```
padding: 0px 250px;
```

Please explain, why you

> [...] can't use padding as I have background color around that which
>   is a lighter color, I don't want the entire thing to be that
>   color.[...]

Or please provide the surrounding code.

Comment: I have background color around it, meaning if I use padding it will expand this darker background color over it, which I am trying to avoid. I essentially have a light grey on both sides, & the webpage down the middle.

Comment: That's it, except that white area on the right is also a background color, done with

* {
background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

Comment: you could alter the margin to: `margin: 0px 0px 0px 250px;` to get the right with your background-color: http://jsfiddle.net/tmfu7j32/4/ . Please read a lot about the box-model: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: I understand what that would do, but as I said I have the light grey on both sides, with this element in the center of the page. Would I need to create 2 backgrounds (one either side) to do this?

Comment: I see your problem now: with `* {background-color: #cfcfcf}` you set the background-color of **all** elements. Please see my newest fiddle with `body {background-color: #cfcfcf}` as well as `text-align:center` instead of `padding`: http://jsfiddle.net/tmfu7j32/6/